# TCL command so that I can get the previous month?

Tags: tcl

Hello I want my script to be ran for the previous month. Is there a quick command in TCL where I can get the previous month?

Comment: No language (AFAIK) has a single command for such an obscure op.  You could use the clock format command with %m, and then: lastMonth = ((currentMonth + 10) % 12) + 1.  Converting to human readable month name is more code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Get the current month as an integer (%k format is month without leading zero)
set month_num [clock format [clock seconds] -format %k]

# Get prev month number.
set prev_month_num [expr {$month_num - 1}]

# Shortcut here to avoid using "clock scan" or "clock format" more than necessary.
set prev_month [lindex "Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov" $prev_month_num]
```

Answer (score 0):

> No language (AFAIK) has a single command for such an obscure op.

Not a single command, but Tcl will surprise you big time:

```
clock format [clock scan "last month"] -format %B
```